Is stress-energy tensor really symmetric?
In learning stress-energy tensor from Gravitation by MTW (pages: end of 130 continued begin of 132) I have problem.
Authors say: spacetime is a river of 4-momentum. And then two steps:
step1 : take 1-form $\Sigma$. stress-energy tensor $T$, takes it and gives a 4-vector $p$ which is momentum crossing 3-volume of $\Sigma$ in positive sense:
$$T(..., \Sigma)=p$$
step2: Then it takes a vector $w$ and gives
$$T(w,\Sigma)=w.p$$
My problem is this: At the point we want calculate $T(w,\Sigma)$ we have a 4-momentum vector $q$. $\Sigma$ has a dual vector say $s$. In step1, 4-momentum crossing 3-volume of $\Sigma$ will be projection of $q$ on $s$ which (times $|s|$) is named $p$. Then in step2 we project $p$ on $w$ (and times $|w|$).
In short: take $q$, project it on $s$, project the result on $w$ and times $|s||w|$.
But this with change by changing order of $s$ and $w$. In contrast with the symmetry property of $T$ :( Where I am wrong?

More on symmetric SEM tensor.

If the metric is symmetric, then the Christoffel symbols are symmetric (in lower indices), and thus the Ricci tensor is symmetric, and thus the Einstein and SEM tensors are symmetric. We usually take the metric to be symmetric.

I want to know where I am wrong in understanding this tensor. something is wrong in my explanation. Badly wrong! I can't find it!
